# Table Valued CLR Function with SQL date return type

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I'm trying to create a CLR (C#) table valued function that returns a table of dates.

```
[SqlFunction(
   DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
   FillRowMethodName = "FindDates_FillRow",
   TableDefinition = "ReturnDate date")]
public static IEnumerable BusinessDays(SqlDateTime startDate, SqlDateTime endDate)
{
    //function body
}

public static void FindDates_FillRow(
object resultObj,
out SqlDateTime returnDate)
{
    dayResult result = (dayResult)resultObj;
    returnDate = result.Date;
}
```

The above code results in an error because the SqlDateTime type creates a method signature on FillRow that differs from what SQL Server expects given the TableDefinition attribute.

> SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6258, Level 16, State 1,
>   Procedure BusinessDays, Line 1 Function signature of "FillRow" method
>   (as designated by SqlFunctionAttribute.FillRowMethodName) does not
>   match SQL declaration for table valued CLR function'BusinessDays' due
>   to column 1.

If I change the TableDefinition to a datetime type, everything works but since there is no SqlDate type, how can I return a date type? Is this even possible or do I just need to use datetime on the CLR side and cast to a date in my SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SqlDate type in system.data.sqltypes, and no other data type that would contain only a date. The way to do it is to pass a datetime and convert it in SQL(if you really need conversion to Date).

Comment: I need a date type because the primary use case for this function will be joining on the date column of other tables. I'm marking this as the solution since what I was hoping doesn't seem to be possible and casting is currently my best option. I believe one other way would be to create an SQL inline wrapper function that performs the cast operation (so as to avoid redundant code/casting on every join).

Comment: I do not think there is the need for conversion if the datetime value is with '00:00:00'. You need the casting to date only if you have 'junk' to cut from your datetime. Otherwise do not do the extra work as sql will do it for you.